# NO_SQL_DATA error when deleting a record, firedac, delphi 10.3.1

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

using sql server and delphi 10.3.1, and firedac.

I am using cached updates, with autocommit on.

I keep managing to get my data into a state where the record has been deleted from the database, and I have also deleted that record in the dataset.

then, when it attempts to commit the change to the database(where the data no longer exists), I get an error: 
[my application] raised exception class emssqlNativeException with message [firedac][Phys][odbc][sqlncli11.dll] SQL_NO_DATA
and then I can't clear the cached updates flag on the dataset, because there is stuff 'sitting' there.

my question - how can I get it to NOT return that error?  because it's really not an error, it's trying to delete a record that no longer exists.  I am not finding ANY documentation on the update options on a query, so is there a flag there I need to set?

Comment: Use `OnUpdateError` to handle update errors. For updates you want to ignore / skip after they error out return `eaApplied` for the `AAction`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle update errors in `OnUpdateError` and perform any additional checks before deciding how to proceed. Blindly pretending all deletes worked would be something like:

```
procedure TForm1.FDQuery1UpdateError(ASender: TDataSet; AException:
    EFDException; ARow: TFDDatSRow; ARequest: TFDUpdateRequest; var AAction:
    TFDErrorAction);
begin
   if ARequest = ARDelete then AAction := eaApplied;
end;
```

Read the online help for [OnUpdateError](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.OnUpdateError) for more information.